# Renormalization of non-local product of operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, renormalization, greens-functions, non-locality

In [*Unraveling hadron structure with generalized parton distributions*](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0504030) by Belitsky and Radyushkin, appendix G, eq. (G.47) it is said that for renormalization of an on-local product of operators such as the one presented in eq. (G.39) you have not only to compute the Green function but also to project firstly in color and Dirac indices of the vertices.

I don't understand the reason why you should do that.